# Chromium & Chrome fails to open/load the UI on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, chromium, gpu

I run the following in terminal:

```
$ chromium-browser
[15433:15433:1015/193928:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13835)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[15433:15433:1015/193928:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4021)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[15433:15433:1015/193928:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[15433:15433:1015/193928:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[15514:15514:1015/193938:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13835)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[15514:15514:1015/193938:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4021)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[15514:15514:1015/193938:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[15514:15514:1015/193938:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[15546:15546:1015/193948:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13835)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[15546:15546:1015/193948:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4021)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[15546:15546:1015/193948:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[15546:15546:1015/193948:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
^X[15555:15555:1015/193958:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13835)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_INNOCENT_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
[15555:15555:1015/193958:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4021)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
[15555:15555:1015/193958:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
[15555:15555:1015/193958:ERROR:gpu_channel_manager.cc(222)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers cannot recover from problems.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 chromium-browser
```

This however does not happen if I reboot. It is only after an unspecified amount of time that both Chromium and Chrome are unable to start, and I am not sure what makes them unresponsive.

Since I am using FF as my main browser, it might be after I am playing some Youtube videos.

I do not have flash installed on my Ubuntu for any of the browsers or in general anywhere.

I have reposted this here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=656347 but I am not sure how much they read into the issues on the Chromium bug board. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Can you search for the setting that enables hardware acceleration for your graphics card in Chrome/Chromium and disable that?

Comment: It did not help unfortunately. And even if it would have, they just run too slow and lag too much to use them like that.